# How to compile a Unity scope? (Or: how to use libraries in Vala?)

Tags: unity, libraries, vala, scopes

I'm currently learning Vala, and after going through the basics I wanted to do an actual small project to make it more fun. For this, I thought creating a scope for Unity would be perfect (in this case, a Scope for the Music lens to search MPD).

However, documentation on doing something like this is sparse. Therefore, I hope to be able to put together a tutorial on writing a scope in Vala by first going through it myself with the help of Ask Ubuntu.

What I'm currently stuck on, is how to compile my scope in such a way that I can use Unity's library. I've installed libunity-dev (was this necessary?), however, when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
$ valac --pkg libunity ./unity-scope-mpd.vala
error: Package `libunity' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

(Note: I have experience in programming in Java and PHP, but haven't done large projects in the former, so please take that into account in an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
 dpkg -L libunity-dev
```

shows that the `vapi` file is actually called `unity.vapi`. Have you tried

```
valac --pkg unity ./unity-scope-mpd.vala
```

?

In general, the package name should be equal to the pkg-config name. You can do a `ls /usr/lib/pkgconfig` to see that there's a `unity.pc`.