# Is there a way to search an MPD library with the music lens?

Tags: lenses, mpd, scopes

I use MPD, along with the GUI client Sonata to play all my music. It works quite well, but none of my music shows up in the music lens (since I don't use Banshee or Rhythmbox, it's just empty). Has anyone created an MPD scope for the music lens so that my music would show up? I thought I read in some now-forgotten place that someone was working on one.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not alone: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85080/how-to-compile-a-unity-scope-or-how-to-use-libraries-in-vala

Comment: Interesting. So maybe there just isn't any way quite yet?

Comment: Yep, I was going to do that but then I had to graduate. I might pick the project up in the summer again, but don't count on it or you can only be disappointed :)

Comment: I see. I won't count on it, but will still harbor a wee hope that you'll make it possible one day. Hope your last semester went well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible.